# How to create a ROI and count both black and white pixels within that ROI?

Tags: image-processing, pixel, binary-image, image-thresholding

I have the following b&W image with the ROI (Region of Interest) shown as dashed green lines with the solid line in the centre. I am hoping to develop some code where the ROI can be automatically drawn in by adding 30% of the distance between the two solid green lines to either side of both solid green lines (as shown in the image as dashed green lines). I am then hoping to get the number of black and white pixels within both areas between the dashed green lines.
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPLV3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oirwX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdRTy.png)

Comment: Not very clear. What's a *"consistently coloured pixel"* please? Consistent with what? What's 20% of a boundary please? A boundary is a line, so what's 20% of a line? Maybe you could add a third image with the pixels you want to count coloured differently?

Comment: Please provide 2 further images - the black and white one without annotations, and just the green annotations, both separately.

Comment: Also your diagram doesn't match your textual description. If the dotted buffer around the solid green line is 20% of the distance between the green lines, the buffer should grow fatter where the solid lines are further apart...

Comment: Your right, the dotted buffer should get thicker where the distance between the green lines grows.